# Is it reasonable to use the order of magnitude between two calculated probabilities to give a ballpark figure for the odds of an occurrence happening?

Tags: probability, game-theory

Is it reasonable to use the order of magnitude between two calculated probabilities to give a ballpark figure for the odds of an occurrence happening?

For  example:  I have a model for a tournament with two classes of player.
I have calculated the probability of a player from each class scoring the maximum number of points possible.

Probability of an H type player achieving the highest score possible is:
1/ 83,521

Probability of a L type player achieving the highest score possible:
1/ 3.906E+17

In this model we will assume the calculated probabilities are valid, and that that there is always one type H player that has won the highest score possible and is ranked number 1 on the leader-board for the tournament.

There is also a rule that says if a type L player ties for first place with an H player then the tie goes to the L player.  The number one leader-board rank will always be an H player unless an L player can achieve the maximum points possible to kick the H player out of first place through the tie breaker rule. No other player combinations are being considered.

The difference in the orders of magnitude for the two highest score probabilities as noted above is 13 (!? super layperson here)

For this model could one ballpark a figure and say that the odds of first place on the leader-board not being a type H player is approximately 1 in 10 trillion?

Thank you very much.

Comment: I don't think the probabilities you've specified and the model assumptions are consistent with each other. The model assumes that there is always a type $H$ player that has won the highest score possible, so the probability of a type $H$ player achieving the highest score possible would then be $1$, not $1/83,521$.

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply.  Let us assume for a moment that you are right and the probability of an H player in first place on the leaderboard is 1. To answer the question as posted, if it required that an L type player score the maximum points possible to win an automatic tie breaker to win first place from H, and the probability of that is as noted above, would the order of magnitude of difference between H type an L type which is now 17, express the approximate probability of that happening? So, 1 out 100 quadrillion chance of first place not being an H type player? Thanks

Comment: The chance of of first place not being an H type player is the chance of first place being the L type player. And that's $1/3.906E+17.$

Comment: The assumption about there always being a H player in first place with maximum points is because there is a sufficient number of H players in the tournament that despite any individual H player's calculated probability of 1/83,521 at achieving a perfect score it is likely that at least one will.  Maybe the H players odds are irrelevant to the probability of L displacing H? Main question is if it is reasonable to ballpark the probability of H being displaced from first place on the leader-board by an L type player by rounding to an order of magnitude, and expressing it in terms of odds.

Comment: Hi Kurt G.. Thank you.  Yes I am just realizing what you just said that the H probability issue is not relevant.  Just whether or not L can achieve a perfect score or not. Thanks to all on this forum.  An amazing community.  Now I can ponder all of this for my next question!

Comment: @sicluceatlux Oh, nevermind. I misunderstood how the model is set up!